# “Combine” pairs of list items using CSS

Tags: css

Given

```
<ul>
  <li class="label">City</li>
  <li class="value">New York</li>
  <li class="label">State</li>
  <li class="value">NY</li>
  <li class="label">ZIP</li>
  <li class="value">10010</li>
 </ul>
```

is there a way to render it as

- City: New York
- State: NY
- ZIP: 10010

instead of the normal

- City
- New York
- State
- NY
- ZIP
- 10010

using only CSS? I can’t change the source and can’t use Javascript.

Comment: sure - what effort have you made?

Comment: Many combinations of display: inline, block, and list-item.

Comment: Getting the colon is easy using ::after. I don’t see how to combine the items.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work: Float the label and change the value to a block.

```
.label {float:left}
.label::after {content: ": "; white-space: pre}
.value {display: block}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mccaskey/b76nkr8q/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out (only tested in Firefox and Chrome desktop)

```css
.label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.label::before {
  content: "\2022";
  padding-right: 3px;
  font-size: 120%;
}
.label::after {
  content: ":";
}
.value {
  display: inline;
}
.value::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="label">City</li>
  <li class="value">New York</li>
  <li class="label">State</li>
  <li class="value">NY</li>
  <li class="label">ZIP</li>
  <li class="value">10010</li>
 </ul>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/xm8oL4bf/

**credit**

Line break trick credit to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/injecting-line-break/)

Comment: Hmm . . . Use margin, padding, and text-indent to mimic list formatting . . . And a \A to mimic a block. I guess so. I was hoping to preserve the list-item machinery for indenting, wrapping, setting list-style-item, etc. For an ordered list, I guess I could use counters. Hmm. . . .Still hoping for something less brute-force-y and more list-y.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
li { display: inline; list-style-type: none; }

li:nth-child(2n + 1):after { content : ':'; margin-left: 5px; }

li:nth-child(2n +1):before { content: "\2022"; display: inline; margin-right: 5px; }

li:nth-child(2n):after { content: ''; display: block; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="label">City</li>
  <li class="value">New York</li>
  <li class="label">State</li>
  <li class="value">NY</li>
  <li class="label">ZIP</li>
  <li class="value">10010</li>
</ul>
```